# How to send autometically text in whatsapp. with flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, share, whatsapp

I want to send auto messge on whatsapp, i am creating a news app i need when created a news from admin panel then autometically send news details in whatsapp groups and contacts without any confirmaion. just news creating and auto sending news on whatsapp.....???

send auto news on whatsapp groups and contacts

Comment: Present the code with your best effort and show us the specific error or problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

**you can't** send messages in Whatsapp without a confirmation, sharing text contents to WhatsApp can just open a screen where the input is filled with that text, and the user should manually confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

You can't.

**Long answer**

You'll need to use share_plus plugin to share text or media from your app to whatsapp and others. Then the content you shared will be on the user's textfield for approval.